# checkbox in jquery Tabs different on click behavior in Chrome & Firefox

Tags: jquery, firefox, checkbox, jquery-ui-tabs

I have a jquery UI tab with checkboxes on the tab headers like so http://jsfiddle.net/bSdbG/494/

It works fine in Chrome, but in Firefox, if you click the checkbox of the tab that is currently opened, the page will be scrolled to the tab content. How can I prevent that to happen?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can take the input outside of the a, and then restyle using css.

http://jsfiddle.net/bSdbG/497/

The problem is that jquery's click handler for the a element is running.